# Upload an Image to DB2 database using jsp

Tags: jsp, db2, image-upload

Hi I am working on my final year project which is online book sales management system using mobile sms. DB2 is the database i am using. I want help regarding image uploading to my data base using jsp or servlets and vice-verse. Please help. I have been searching for it, but i can-not understand the concept used.
Can any body help me with the resources of any kind or recommend me book on this topic.
  There are many books on PHP but not for JSP :(
-thaks.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp

Answer (score 0):

Your JSPs will need to use Java code that interacts with the database via the standard JDBC API that nearly all Java programs use for database access. DB2 provides a lightweight JCC Type 4 universal driver that complies with the JDBC standard, without requiring a full DB2 client to be installed on your Java EE server. Somewhere in your Java code (probably in one or more dedicated POJO classes that are referenced by your JSPs) you'll develop methods that will connect to a DB2 database and execute SQL statements. Since a single image can exceed the maximum column size of 32K, you'll want to define your image column to use the BLOB data type, which can store potentially large amounts binary data. Writing and retrieving BLOB and CLOB data requires the use of specialized JDBC functions that aren't used for traditional data types such as INTEGER, CHAR, VARCHAR, DATE, TIME, etc.

Comment: can you give reference of any book for studying this topic? that will be really help full. -thanks